# heavy RoR app horizontally scaled on AWS needs efficient SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ssl, amazon-web-services, openssl

I am running a Rails app on the AWS infrastructure using several EC2 instances, a RDS DB, a round robin session-sticky load balancer and Route 53.

The application is serving pages for several domain names (same app looks and functions different depending on domain name).

The Rails code is hosted on a NFS share on a staging instance where the web server is running in development mode, while the other boxes load the apache config and application code via NFS and run in production mode.

What I'd like to do is to SSL-enable the whole thing as we're starting to process payments and whatnot. Due to the nature of the application and the heavy apache/Passenger optimization in place, I can't set up a vhost for each domain, but rather use a wildcard for www.* to load pretty much the same code, and the app does the rest internally.

Haven't really been able to figure out an ideal way to resolve this. Would anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you start per vhost a different application or is it always the same app?
Because if you already distinguish between layouts in Rails having one www.* SSL host there should be really no issue with this.

Comment: It's the same app all over. For plain HTTP I'm using one single vhost www.* - but for the SSL-enabled setup I should be able to add any number of them SSL vhosts without having to start different instances of the application

Comment: I guess you can do that through <vhosts> and proxies.. not sure how that works with SSL though.

Comment: We've got the HTTP side of things working quite nice... problem is when having to run different SSL-enabled domains without having different vhosts. They would need to have different SSL certs. Not even sure that's possible :(

Comment: No I think that's not possible. You can however get a cert for multiple domains IIRC .. but that's pretty costly..

Comment: I think this is a nice solution. I have indeed found sites that sell it for 1000 or more but Comodo sells a MDC for 100 domains for $150/year, which is definitely reasonable... setting up 10 sites with their own individual cert would cost more than this MDC for 100. :) Thank you so much for your comment, would you post it as answer please?

Comment: Done .. glad you found a solution.. Check out the wikipedia link I posted as it seems Comodo isn't trusted on Android.. (Don't know if the chart is correct though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of discussion in the comments we came to this conclusion:

The application is currently hosted in one single `<vhost>` on Apache where the Application does the differentiation between hostnames for the different layouts.

The problem here is to support SSL without having to setup each domain with it's own certificate and a different vhost as that would require running the Rails app multiple times where it's unnecessary.

By using a **Multiple Domain Certificate (MDC)** this problem can be solved with only one vhost and one certificate, but MDCs are more expensive than normal certificates. So depending on the number of domains you need to support it may be cheaper/easier to just do it manually with multiple certs, or opt to pay the more expensive MDC but save time and maintenance cost.

While at it I found this nice wikipedia comparison of Certificate Authorities and their trust level in different browsers:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSL_certificates_for_web_servers

Comment: A quick side note. I was able to get a Comodo MDC at $140 / year for 5 domains then $30 / year for each additional domain. This is fair considering market pricing and also allows us the flexibility to run a single vhost on all of our nodes.